# What is the purpose of making a non-blocking lock?

Tags: python-3.x

In python multithreading (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire), the acquire allows lock to be non-blocking.

What is the purpose of making a non-blocking lock?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are looking for? The question currently seems to be aiming either for the trivial "the purpose of non-blocking is not to block", or some opinion-based/subjective examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When invoked with the blocking argument set to False, do not block. If a call with blocking set to True would block, return False immediately; otherwise, set the lock to locked and return True.

This makes it so you can attempt to acquire a lock, and if it is not free, do something else or simply continue execution.

```py
if lock.acquire(blocking=False):
    do_thread_unsafe_operation()
    lock.release()
else:
    do_something_else()
```